# NetBSD syslog timestamp format

Tags: syslog, timestamp, netbsd

Syslog uses a timestamps like the following:

Sep 19 13:36:56

Is there a way to adjust the format (to add the year for example) without touching the source code? I am some what shocked to find that the answer to this appears to be so obscure, unless I am just googling the wrong things.

Answer (score 2):

Timestamp format is indeed hardcoded in make_timestamp() function:

http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/usr.sbin/syslogd/syslogd.c?annotate=HEAD